# how to disable auto resizing in all view controllers

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have to remove the auto-resizing applied on all view controllers in my project. Is there a way to disable auto-resizing applied on all view controllers.

Comment: Have you looked at `autoresizesSubviews:`?
 You might be able to disable auto-resizing for each `UIView`. Is that what you want to do?
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622425-autoresizessubviews

Comment: What do you mean by *"remove the auto-resizing applied on all view controllers"*? Have you set up constraints, and you want to remove them so you can do it over? Or do you really want to ***disable*** Auto-Layout completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You are able to Disable **Autolayout** in view controller But there is no direct way to disable **Auto-Resizing** in iOS. 

You need to manage PIN in **Auto-Resizing**. Set appropriate PIN of relevant object. Please review attached screenshot for **Auto-Resizing**.

Happy Coding! :)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from storyboard by selecting auto layout

[image: description]

[image: Choose Use Auto Layout]

Comment: Please provide more than just images when answering. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer